# Create a link to the Unix socket

Tags: unix, socket, hardlink

Is there a possibility to create a hard link for an unix socket? I'm creating a jail and symbolic links won't work, so I'm looking for a solution, how to provide an unix socket inside chrootted environment.

The only idea I'm coming across is to use something like netcat but is there any reliable possibility?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as a duplicate.  The other question just asks about creating listening sockets in the filesystem, this one is about duplicating them.

Comment: Agreed, if I had the rep I would be casting a reopen vote here.

Answer (score 6):

Linux at least would allow you to use a bind mount to make either a directory or alternatively a single file available at multiple places.

```
  # mount --bind /var/MySQL.sock /chroot/var/MySQL.sock
```

Comment: Bind works only for directories, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In the words of the man page `One can also remount a single file (on a single file)`, and I have no problems accessing the MySQL daemon through the socket in the bind mount. But I don't have any chroot set up to test more.

Comment: Parameter list consist on two directories. I mean mounting a link directly, without separated directory. Could you provide your command line I can test against? Is this the above you cited? I tried to make it happen but this doesn't work.

Comment: You can also put the socket in a directory created for this purpose, and bind mount that.

Comment: @FalconMomot, I know but I want to solve problem. I'm aware of a workaround. [;

Comment: How does that not solve the problem?  Bind the directory the socket goes in, see to it that it goes in there, and you're done.

Comment: Doesn't solve - it enforces me creating a separated directory for various set of sockets. I want to specify it more flexible, so is that why I asked for a particular link for a socket if it's possible.

Comment: I know Docker uses single file bind mounts, but the bind command does not accept them. (And your mount command parameters is wrong, it is `--bind` or `-t none -o bind`)

Comment: HBruijn's is the correct answer (with @GertvandenBerg's fix). Thanks for this! See: http://www.mardy.it/blog/2018/10/how-to-bind-mount-single-file.html